# Concatenating strings in Shell

Tags: linux, shell, unix, scripting

I am facing this issue when concatenating strings Linux shell script

```
apphome="`cd \`dirname $0\` && pwd && cd - >/dev/null`"
echo "***************** APP Home***************"
echo $apphome
libdir="${apphome}/lib"
echo "**********Lib  DIR ***********************"
echo ${libdir}
```

`echo $apphome` and `echo $libdir` gives following output

```
***************** APP Home***************
/product/abc/project1/cba/STADATA
**********Lib  DIR ***********************
/libduct/abc/project1/cba/STADATA
```

why don't it append /lib to the libdir correctly, could anybody explain me what is going wrong here

Comment: Copy **just that bit you posted** into its own file and run it directly using `sh` or `bash`. You're introducing error somewhere that you're not posting.

Comment: Somehow, $apphome ends with a carriage return. Are you using a Windows shell?

Comment: `$()` nests, backticks do not.  Use: `$( cd $( dirname $0 ) && pwd )` ( no need to cd back, it's a subshell) or `$( dirname $( readlink -f $0 ))`.  Backticks are evil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just quote the string

```
libdir="${apphome}/lib"
```

Complete script

```
#!/bin/sh
apphome="`cd \`dirname $0\` && pwd && cd - >/dev/null`"
echo "***************** APP Home***************"
echo $apphome
libdir="${apphome}/lib"
echo "**********Lib  DIR ***********************"
echo ${libdir}
```

gives

```
***************** APP Home***************
/product/abc/project1/cba/STADATA
**********Lib  DIR ***********************
/product/abc/project1/cba/STADATA/lib
```

Comment: Ok which shell are you using? How is the script executed?

Comment: If it keeps failing you I suggest printf which is bullet-proof :)

Comment: i have tried executing script as sh scriptname.sh and ./scriptname.sh
both gives same error. 
How can I know which shell I am using.

Comment: The behavior is dependent on which shell (e.g. ksh, bash, csh) you're using. This is a bit like asking how to write a program and not specifying whether you're using C or Python.

Comment: I copied all the content of the script into test.sh, now the scirpt is running. I don't know what makes this wired behaviour

Comment: Run the script as follows `bash -x ./scriptname.sh`.  That will give you a trace of what it is doing, which should lead to a solution.

Comment: Nothing against down votes but a comment would help to understand what's the problem...

Comment: [Glenn Jackman](http://stackoverflow.com/users/7552/glenn-jackman)'s comment is the best hint